# php mysql issue with printing value on html page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to query MySQL DB and print a single result on the page using PHP.

It's always going to be a single result, so I'm not sure if I need to loop

In any case, would anyone mind advising why the below doesn't work?

Thank you!!

```
    // Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
 else {
    echo "success";
}

$sql = "SELECT sum(Discounted_Value) as id FROM Orders WHERE Year = 2017";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Total 2017 "  $row["id"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there will be only one result you can simplify code to:

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(Discounted_Value) as id FROM Orders WHERE Year = 2017";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo "Total 2017 " . $row["id"] . "<br>";  // Don't forget dots for concatenation
```